# Put data-id value into form action

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button to pass data in an array.

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-id='["id12345", "abdce"]' class="open-EditNetworkDialog btn btn-primary" href="#editForm">Edit</a>
```

When i click the button, runs the below javascript code into a modal with a form. My intention is to pass certain value to the form's input textbox. and also pass a value in  action="".

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-EditNetworkDialog", function () {
    var varAccountDetail = $(this).data('id');
    $(".modal-body #network").val( varAccountDetail[0] );
    $(".modal-body #name").val( varAccountDetail[1] );
});
```

I am able to send the value "abcde" to the form's input. 
How do i replace the form action with the value "id12345"?
eg. `<form action="id12345">`

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Edit</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="">
            <div class="form-group">Name: <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Name" id="name" value=""></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the community..!

You can change the actions of form by using this single line of code.

```
$('form').attr('action', 'id12345');
```

`id12345` can be changed with your variable, like this:

```
$('form').attr('action', varAccountDetail[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to change the action of `form` tag

JS Code -

```
$('form').attr('action', '<Value that you want to put in action>');
```

In your case, it should look something like below

```
$('form').attr('action', varAccountDetail[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit your form action

```
$('form').attr('action', varAccountDetail[0]);
```